# Starting uploading files on command button click

Tags: jakarta-ee, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2, commandbutton

i'm using jsf2.2 primefaces 6.0 and i already implemented a solution to upload files and clicking on command button to confirm the demand.The problem that every user will upload files even when the demand is not validated which cause charging the repository for nothing.
I want to correct that by uploading files only when the user is clicking on command button to validate the demand.

Here the Xhtml code :

```
<p:fileUpload
                    fileUploadListener="#{imageUploader.handleFileUpload}"
                    label="Ajouter" uploadLabel="Télécharger" cancelLabel="Annuler"
                    mode="advanced" auto="false" sizeLimit="10485760" multiple="true"
                    fileLimit="10" fileLimitMessage="Maximum 10 images"
                    dragDropSupport="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" 
                    invalidFileMessage="Format de fichier non valide" invalidSizeMessage="Taille maximum 10 MB"/>

<p:commandButton update="@form" disabled="#{not facesContext.postback or facesContext.validationFailed}"
                    style="background:#6FDC6F;color: #FFFFFF;float:left"
                    styleClass="customStyleButton"
                    action="#{demandeBean.doAddDemande()}" value="confirmer demande">

                </p:commandButton>
```

Here the java Bean code:

```
public class ImageUploader {
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{demandeBean}")
    private DemandeBean demandeBean;


    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        String shortImagePath = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";

        if (uploadedFile != null && uploadedFile.getContents() != null) {
            try {

                byte[] contents = uploadedFile.getContents();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DirectoryInitilizer.IMAGE_DIR + "/" + shortImagePath);
                fos.write(contents);
                fos.close();

                demandeBean.getImages().add(shortImagePath);
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("pb", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is not uploaded.");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why you've put allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" but your file extension in the bean is always jpg?

Comment: it's a little mistake

Comment: viewed 31 times and no answer !!!!